# How to find all voted user against each debate in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a debate collection, which holds all the debates and another collection holds the votes against each debate. So I wanted to retrieve all the debates with a new user flag (isVoted) if I found any user in the vote collection against each debate.

**Vote model:**

```
var voteSchema = new Schema({
user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },     // One who votes
debate: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Debate' }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

**Debate Model:**

```
var debateSchema = new Schema({
category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Category' },
question: { type: String, required: true },
Votes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

**Query**

```
DebateData.aggregate([
    {
        $match: query
    },
    {
        $sort : { createdAt : -1 }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
          from: "votes", // must be the PHYSICAL name of the collection
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "debate",
          as: "votes"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            'isVoted': {
                $cond: { if: { $eq: [ '$votes.user', ObjectId(req.query.userId) ] }, then: 'true', else: 'false' }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            '_id': 1,
            'question': 1,
            'isVoted': 1,
            'createdAt': 1
        }
    },
]).then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, status: 200, message: 'Debate videos', data: result});
}).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, status: 500, message: err.message })
});
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "60e81f8299a4809658290d80",
        "votes": 10,
        "category": [
            {
                "name": "Hockey"
            }
        ],
        "question": "What is football?",
        "isVoted": true,
        "createdAt": "2021-07-09T10:05:54.498Z"
    },
{
        "_id": "60e438f1194949add0cc2074",
        "votes": 12,
        "category": [
            {
                "name": "Cricket"
            }
        ],
        "question": "What is football?",
        "isVoted": false,
        "createdAt":  "2021-07-06T11:05:21.654Z"
    }
]
}
```

**Current output:**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "60e81f8299a4809658290d80",
        "votes": 10,
        "category": [
            {
                "name": "Hockey"
            }
        ],
        "question": "What is football?",
        "createdAt": "2021-07-09T10:05:54.498Z"
    },
{
        "_id": "60e438f1194949add0cc2074",
        "votes": 12,
        "category": [
            {
                "name": "Cricket"
            }
        ],
        "question": "What is football?",
        "createdAt":  "2021-07-06T11:05:21.654Z"
    }
]
}
```

**Vote Data:**

```
{
   data: [
        {
          "user": "69881f8299a480965829ytr267",
          "debate": "60e81f8299a4809658290d80"
        }
   ]
 }
```

Comment: could you provide some input out put data sample ?

Comment: thank you pls provide sample data of vote and debate ?

Comment: did you use aggrerate ?